# Overload resolution of Eigen's operator()() when wrapping it with Boost.Python

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, boost-python

I am in the process of wrapping a C++ library using Boost.Python. Some of the functions therein return `Eigen::MatrixXd` objects (a [dynamically sized double-precision matrix class](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html)). On the Python side I just need to access the dimensions of the matrices, this is easy, and retrieve some matrix elements with Eigen's overloaded `operator()()` method. Unfortunately there are 4 such overloaded methods, one has to pick the right one manually, i.e. giving Boost.Python a function pointer typedef with the correct signature, something along the lines

```
namespace bpy = boost::python;
bpy::class_<Eigen::MatrixXd>("MatrixXd",
        "Variable-size double-precision matrix class",
        bpy::init<const Eigen::MatrixXd&>()
    )
        .def("__call__", static_cast<parop_signature>(&Eigen::MatrixXd::operator()))
        // ...
;
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out what the correct signature of the function is. "Operationally" it should take two integer indices and return a double value. However,

```
typedef const double& (Eigen::MatrixXd::*parop_signature)(int, int) const;
```

results in the following compilation error (Mac OS X, clang++ in C++11 mode, Boost.Python V1.61):

```
address of overloaded function 'operator()' cannot be static_cast to type
      'const double &(MatrixXd::*)(int, int) const'
  ...static_cast<const double& (Eigen::MatrixXd::*)(int, int) const>(&Eigen::MatrixXd::operator())
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/eigen/current/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:111:41: note: 
      candidate function
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE CoeffReturnType operator()(Index row, Index col) const
                                        ^
/usr/local/eigen/current/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:171:5: note: 
      candidate function
    operator()(Index index) const
    ^
/usr/local/eigen/current/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:334:5: note: 
      candidate function
    operator()(Index row, Index col)
    ^
/usr/local/eigen/current/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:392:5: note: 
      candidate function
    operator()(Index index)
```

Fair enough, you'd say: but I cannot figure out how I can tell Boost.Python that `CoeffReturnType` is actually a `double` here (or maybe a `const double&`, who knows?), and that `IndexType` will resolve to a plain `int` at the end of the day. I have tried all sorts of combinations of `typedef`-s with or without `const` qualifiers.

Even tried to declare a C++11 -style function pointer like

```
auto eigen_indexfn = std::mem_fn<double(int,int)>(&Eigen::MatrixXd::operator());
```

, no success, I get

```
candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Tp'
mem_fn(_Rp _Tp::* __pm)
^
```

Is there someone who has gone through this already and can provide me with the correct signature of what for all intents and purposes should be as simple as "`double Eigen::MatrixXd::operator(int, int)`" ? Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: The return type is not actually a `double`, but a type that also allows assignment to that position inside the matrix.

Comment: @xeo: Could you be more explicit? Do you know for sure the return type is a `double&` (I assume this is what you meant by "a type that also allows assignment to that position inside the matrix"? Do you know the `operator()(Index, Index)` function is non-`const`, or is there perhaps a `const` version as well? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @xeo me again: non-const signature does not work, I get "`cannot be static_cast to type 'parop_signature' (aka
      'double &(MatrixXd::*)(int, int)')`"

Comment: Reading through Eigen's source, there should be both `const Scalar& operator()(Index, Index) const` as well as `Scalar& operator()(Index, Index)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error origins from the fact that `Eigen::Index` is not `int` but defaults to `ptrdiff_t`. Just because `int` can implicitly be cast to `Eigen::Index` does not mean that you can cast a function pointer which requires `Eigen::Index` to a function pointer which requires `int`. If that was possible, you would end up passing integers of the wrong size over the stack.

Addendum: If you really prefer `int` over `ptrdiff_t`, you can define `EIGEN_DEFAULT_DENSE_INDEX_TYPE` to `int` before including Eigen, [as documented here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html), be aware that this will break ABI compatibility.

Comment: yes, this was the breakthrough, many thanks! But that's not the complete story, I add an answer below for reference, while accepting your as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @xao and @chtz for their help. For reference (pun intended) I show the solution here that finally worked, with comments.

Part one, the signature of Eigen's parenthesis operator for accessing matrix elements:

```
// const element access in dynamically-sized double matrices
// note that the Index type is ptrdiff_t
// and the CoeffReturnType is const double&
typedef const double& (Eigen::MatrixXd::*parop_signature)(ptrdiff_t,ptrdiff_t) const;
```

Part two, an appropriate return policy must be defined. We want to use the `const double&` returned by `operator()()` so the policy will be `copy_const_reference`:

```
bpy::class_<Eigen::MatrixXd>("MatrixXd",
    "Variable-size double-precision matrix class",
    bpy::init<const Eigen::MatrixXd&>()
)
    .def("__call__", static_cast<parop_signature>(&Eigen::MatrixXd::operator()),
        bpy::return_value_policy<bpy::copy_const_reference>())
```

After going through all this it compiles and can be invoked from Python correctly.